# Bash ${..//../..} not changing all occurrences

Tags: bash, sh

I need to replace "insignificant" parts of a name. This needs to be done in a bash script. To do this, I need to remove the middle words "VAN", "DEN", "DE" and "DER".

To do this, I'm using the built-in replace (problem reduced to 2 lines):

```
line="STIG VAN DE WYNKELE"; 
line=${line//@(' VAN '|' DEN '|' DE '|' DER ')/' '};
echo $line;
```

Output:

```
STIG DE WYNKELE
```

Expected output:

```
STIG WYNKELE
```

It seems like the @(...) is matching one of the middle words, removing all occurences of this one middle word, but it doesn't match others.

The question: Am I doing something wrong in my syntax? If not, how would I remove those words? sed requires files, while my input is a variable, and the altered text should be stored in a variable too. ($line should be changed)

Comment: `sed` does not require files, it's a stream editor. `foo=$(echo "$foo" | sed ...)` is a common idiom.

Comment: Common, but usually unnecessary if `$foo` is short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bash` doesn't backtrack. First, it finds `VAN` in the input:

```
STIG VAN DE WYNKELE
    ^^^^^|
```

(where `|` represents its pointer while scanning).

After replacing `VAN` with , you have

```
STIG DE WYNKELE
     |
```

You'll notice that `DE` is not found in the string starting at `D`; the space you just inserted is not checked by `bash`.

Instead, drop the leading space from each pattern, and delete a match instead of replacing it with a space:

```
echo "${line//@('VAN '|'DEN '|'DE '|'DER ')}"
```

---

Of course, the problem with this is that you now might drop a match that occurs at the end of a word. There isn't away to avoid that with a single match; instead, do multiple replacements in a loop:

```
for word in VAN DEN DE DER; do
    line=${line// $word / }
done
```

Comment: This solved the issue and looks like the best way to do it without any side-effects, thanks!

Comment: It's possible with a single match, but only with look-arounds (not supported in bash).

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the `extglob` option. Also, remove the quotes, and move the space outside of the alternative. You can shorten the expression further:

```
#!/bin/bash
line="STIG VAN DE DEN DER WYNKELE"
shopt -s extglob
line=${line//@(VAN|DE?([NR])) }
echo "$line"
```

By double-quotting $line in the last line, you can see whether the spaces were removed correctly.

Comment: `Need` is a strong word. Imo it is not required to use `extglob` here

Comment: Uh you, are right, I overlooked that since it is enabled by default on my box.. Thanks!

Comment: Since it removes "van", "de",... in "WYNKELEDE BAR" for example, it's not 100% fit for the current case. However, it looks like a very clean way to fix similar problems, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any `extglob` pattern. You can just use Parameter Expansion:

```
${line/ * / }
```

**Example:**

```
$ line="STIG VAN DE WYNKELE"
$ echo ${line/ * / }
STIG WYNKELE
```

Answer (score 0):

With awk :

```
echo $line | awk '{ if ($2 == "VAN" || $2 == "DEN" || $2 =="DE" || $2=="DER"  ) $2="";  if ($3 == "VAN" || $3== "DEN" || $3 =="DE" || $3=="DER"  ) $3="" ; print }'
```